# typescript checked value is still marked as undefined in function body

Tags: typescript

have if check on var1 and this work as expected except function body in if statement not clear why

```
let var1: number | undefined;
let var2: number;

if (var1) {
  var2 = var1;
  const func = () => {
    var2 = var1;
  };
  func();
  console.log(var2);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's because you can do something like this `var1=undefined; func();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical answer to this question can be found at [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).

In general, it would be prohibitively expensive for the compiler to perform fully accurate [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) that crosses function boundaries.  Functions can be called multiple times from multiple sites; the only way this would work is for the compiler to effectively [inline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) every function call.  For a very simple case like your example code, it is conceivably plausible that the compiler could analyze the types by first transforming it to something like:

```
if (var1) {
    var2 = var1;
    // replace func() with its body
    {
        var2 = var1;
    }
    console.log(var2);
}
```

But to do this all the time "wouldn't be even remotely practical", as mentioned in microsoft/TypeScript#9998.  Instead, the compiler has to take shortcuts to be performant, and any such shortcuts will tend to have false negatives (no errors are reported where there is an actual problem), false positives (errors are reported where there is no actual problem), or both.

TypeScript compiler currently optimistically assumes that calling a function has no effect on control flow analysis, leading to false negatives:

```
if (var1) {
    const func = () => (var1 = undefined);
    func();
    var2 = var1; // no error, but there should be
}
```

and pessimistically assumes that no narrowing has taken place inside the body of a function, leading to false positives, as in your example code:

```
if (var1) {
    const func = () => { 
        var2 = var1; // error, but there shouldn't be
    }; 
    func();
}
```

There is discussion in microsoft/TypeScript#9998 about different possible approaches, and how they lead to problems in other situations.  For now, this is just how it is.

---

So what is the fix here?  Obviously you could inline `func()` yourself.  Another solution is to sidestep the problem by saving the narrowed value `var1` to a new variable (e.g., `var1Saved`, which the compiler will infer as having the narrowed type it is initialized with.  Such a type can never be widened, so it will always be seen as `number` and never `number | undefined`, even inside `func()`:

```
if (var1) {
    const var1Saved = var1;
    const func = () => {
        var2 = var1Saved; // okay
    };
    func();
}
```

That works for this case, but in many cases you will find that functions that close over variables or properties whose types may be narrowed via control flow analysis will often have such problems where the compiler does not know what the actual type of these variables will be.  And the only fully general way to deal with it is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) where you tell the compiler information it can't figure out for itself, and take responsibility for the accuracy of such assertions:

```
if (var1) {
    const func = () => {
        var2 = var1 as number; // okay
    };
    func();
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAbghgTgRgFwQHYFcC2AjEcIA+E6qAJiAGYCWqIpA3AFCiSxwBMKGOeTjjAegEQawGjQDmAGjQB7SAAc4MAMZgqKmMBGoIEkLWXBGVChAAUbBAEoIAb0YQn0eOwgBeF4ibOIQiHAgCsCqIBAUJCrmtgDuVGAAFiJgAM4Q2LKkAJ6Ozg6+vmxunlY+zgC+uU4qsqgpsqAAdMCyEpau1kyVJmbtiLb5zjV1kBGoKh4Wtu4AfBZWkyTk1LSknVXhkdFlTkWTpX7CqLIQeHCycDLY6JCJeGEpCbLowKTpIIzdpvPwNvYbwxSo0ik2iHjmgwKXmKXgQ9EOpzg50u6RuEDugQgj2er1QAHJILgNuUdptxttPvx-NQAB49H79f6+QGsX4AZRgUDo+1+pJZZImnjBsyZUOhPMQHK5DARsgA1jAcr4SRsxlF1t1-N8tNoQMAUmEKDAqPqZDAUga4LcEmEwFkFB96X0-pCIPy1aDphCNoVXBKEBBzWgsLg4PD-PLFcTSWqKeUgA)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let var1: number | undefined
let var2: number | undefined

if (var1) {
    var2 = var1;
    const func = () => {
        var2 = var1;
    }
    func();
    console.log(var2)
}
```

As the value of var2 receives the value of var1, it means that at some point it can be undefined, so you avoid this type of problem.